# Scroll down to a div at the center of page on page load on Mobile view

Tags: javascript

I would like to my site to auto scroll to middle of page or to a certain div located at middle of page on page load in when using a mobile

I am trying to put this but not working. Has an error

```
   if ($(window).width() < 900) { 

    function scrollToElement(myid) {
$(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);}
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: What is `ele`? Also you're not using `myid`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys . I got it working
Here is the code

```
    ;(function($){
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 900) {
   $(window).scrollTo($("#cart-sidebar"))
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Also put the scrollTo plugin